# Transfer Linux VM to another VM

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

I have to transfer a Linux Ubuntu VM to another Linux Ubuntu VM.
For security reasons, I can only transfer files and re-install to the new VM.
(I cannot copy the disk VM to another VM.....).

I intend :
   to GZIP the folder /home/  into a file.
   Copy paste the files into the new VM.

Will it work on the programs I have installed by apt-get ?
What issue I will have to face ?

EDIT:
  This is for a server with different kind of install:
    CUDA, Web server, JVM and Python, and DOS2UNIX, ....

Comment: It will not work as intended. Look in /home/ and you'll see that hardly anything is installed in that location.  Especially not anything that apt-get installs. Mainly what you'll find in your home directory is just your personal files, and some configuration files.

Comment: if I do this:  tar -zcvf /archive_vm_root.tar.gz    /
and copy the content into the new VM, will it works ?

Comment: Creating a tarball of an entire filesystem and then unpacking it on another system will just create a total mess. Go with @xenoid 's suggestion instead.

Answer (score 1):

The title is misleading, you aren't transferring VMs, just trying to rebuild a somewhat equivalent machine (which doesn't even need to be a VM).

It is hard to answer this question without knowing how you use the VM. Is it a web server? Or are you just an end-user machine? For servers lots of things are kept in /var. The program files are in /usr but you saving & restoring this properly is difficult because it contains plenty of links, and you would have to restore the matching installed software information for the package installer.

For a basic end-user machine you would:

1. create a list of the packages you installed explicitly:

   ```
   comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u)
   ```

(this lists only tje top-level packages, not their dependencies)

2. log off you user (or at least exit the graphical desktop)
3. copy /home/{user}
4. you may want to keep a copy of /etc for reference (but don't restore it blindly on the new machine)

And the other machine:

1. create the adequate user (it is more important that it has the same UID that it has the same name)(this is usually done at installation time,)
2. reinstall missing packages
3. restore /home/{user} (from a command prompt)

Then you should be good to go.

If it's a server parts of /var will also be useful, but which ones are dependent on the software used (and some are best not transferred as files (MySQL data, for instance).